# Wiring up a current limiting resistor with an IR LED burns of the LED

Tags: led, resistors, series

I have a 5V DC supply and i am trying to wire an IR led with a resistor in series to it. I have wired it up to a bread board as shown in the pic

[image: Resistor-LED in series]

- The current limiting resistor value is ~ 216 Ohm.
- Using a multimeter's diode setting, i found out the forward voltage for the LED is 1.18 V
- Wiring the circuit as shown in the pic, blows up the LED!

Could you please point out where am i going wrong?

Comment: Check out https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard-and-build-a-led-circuit--mac-54746 for good info on the connectivity on a breadboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See all other answers, in a schematic:

LEFT: what you wanted

RIGHT: what you made

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3biPM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You have wired the circuit incorrectly. The way you placed the resistor on the breadboard actually connects **both** ends of the resistor to the LED's anode, which is then connected **directly** to power. Remember that those five holes are all connected together electrically.

Move the LED's anode to a different group of five holes, then use the resistor connect between power and the anode.

Answer (score 2):

Each of the 5-hole rows is a continuous strip. Your resistor is shorted out, you have applied 5 V to the LED, a high current flows and the LED is destroyed.

---

There is an interesting aside to this. Sub-consciously you knew that each five sockets are connected. You were using this knowledge to connect the red wire to the resistor and the resistor to the LED. For some reason your brain switched off as you plugged both ends of the resistor into the one line hoping that the breadboard would open circuit between the two resistor insertion points. The mind is a strange thing!